# How an offline main domain can influence traffic on an active sub domain

Tags: seo, subdomain, http-code-503

The website(s) design is for a company active in 3 different areas.

As an example lets use the following structure:

```
                    www.example.com 
[sub1.example.com] [sub2.example.com] [sub3.example.com]
```

`sub2.example.com` and `sub3.example.com` are ready to go live but `www.example.com` really isn't and send a 503 HTTP error code. I would like to know if this situation will affect the traffic and ranking of the subdomains ready to go live?

Is it preferable to wait and go live with the main domain? Or there is nothing to "fear" and one doesn't affect the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wait until the www is ready, it's the standard subdomain and will be tested by Google. If you are in a hurry to release sub2 and sub3, make at least a temporary page on www (like "coming soon") which will link to sub2 and sub3.

Show immediately that the subdomains are strongly linked together.